# Two commands in Void loop?

Tags: c++, debounce

So basically I'm making 2 buttons turn on and off 2 different LEDs using debounce.
I got that settled with one button to turn on and off 1 LED.
But how do I make it so I can use the same lines but obviously different names of pins in Void loop?

So this is the one command line, but how do I make 2 commands with the if statement, may I have an example? Thanks

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int inPin = 22;         // the number of the input pin
int inPin2 = 26;
int outPin1 = 13;       // the number of the output pin
int outPin2 = 6;

int state = LOW;      // the current state of the output pin
int reading;           // the current reading from the input pin
int reading2;
int previous = HIGH;    // the previous reading from the input pin
int previous2 = HIGH;


// the follow variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
// will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
long time = 0;         // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounce = 200;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers

//===============================================================================================
void doIt(int outPin)
{
  Serial.print("Button Switch State Change:");
  if (state == HIGH) state = LOW;
  else state = HIGH;
  Serial.println(state);
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Zone1|State: ");
  lcd.print(state ? F("On") : F("Off"));
  Serial.print(state ? F("On") : F("Off"));
  digitalWrite(outPin, state);
}
//===============================================================================================
void setup()
{
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("System Activated");
  //
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Ready...");

  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(outPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(outPin2, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("System Activated");
  Serial.println("Made by Mateo Holguin");
  Serial.println("0 = Light is Off | 1 = Light is On");
  Serial.println("=======================================");
}

//===============================================================================================

void loop()
{
  reading = digitalRead(inPin);
  reading2 = digitalRead(inPin2);

  if (reading == HIGH && previous == LOW && millis() - time > debounce) {
    doIt(outPin1);  
  }
  else if (reading2 == HIGH && previous2 == LOW && millis() - time > debounce){
    doIt(outPin2);
  }



  previous = reading;
  previous2 = reading2;
  time = millis();
}
```

Comment: So basically I just added the sketch to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Use the code below as it is, it's working for me:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int inPin = 22; 
int inPin2 = 26;
int outPin1 = 13;    
int outPin2 = 6;

int state1 = HIGH;
int state2 = HIGH;
int reading;     
int reading2;
int previous = HIGH; 
int previous2 = HIGH;

int debounce = 150;   // the debounce time, increase if the output flickers

//===============================================================================================
void doIt(int outPin, int state)
{
  Serial.print("Button Switch State Change:");
  if (state == HIGH) state = LOW;
  else state = HIGH;
  Serial.println(state);
  lcd.clear();

  if (outPin == outPin1) 
    lcd.print("Zone1|State: ");
  else if (outPin == outPin2)
    lcd.print("Zone2|State: ");

  lcd.print(state ? F("On") : F("Off"));
  Serial.print(state ? F("On") : F("Off"));
  digitalWrite(outPin, state);
}
//===============================================================================================
void setup()
{
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("System Activated");
  //
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Ready...");

  pinMode(inPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(outPin1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(inPin2, INPUT);
  pinMode(outPin2, OUTPUT);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("System Activated");
  Serial.println("Made by Mateo Holguin");
  Serial.println("0 = Light is Off | 1 = Light is On");
  Serial.println("=======================================");
}

//===============================================================================================

void loop()
{
  reading = digitalRead(inPin);
  reading2 = digitalRead(inPin2);
  delay(debounce);

  if (reading == HIGH)
  {
    state1 = !state1;
    doIt(outPin1, state1);  
  }
  else if (reading2 == HIGH){
    state2 = !state2;
    doIt(outPin2, state2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh one question, do I have to do void doIT (int outPin) for both outputs?

Comment: I added what you had, but when I press the button, nothing happens, can you review for me please?

Comment: I put the code as an edit above

Comment: You have a mistake in the loop(), you don't actually need to call `digitalWrite(outPin, state);` since it's already called in the function `doIt()`.

Comment: Another mistake is that you used the same name for two variables which is `outPin`, this one is already used in the function `doIt()`. you need to give it another name, say `outPin1`.

Comment: Sorry that I keep bothering you, but I updated the above sketch, and it still seems to not want to do anything.

Comment: No problem man, I'm still seeing `digitalWrite(outPin, state);` in your loop(), all the way down ??

Comment: I already removed that, sorry I didn't remove it in this discussion, but in my sketch I did.

Comment: Ok, please give me some time, I'll try it out and get back to you.

Comment: You're welcome man, do you really need to do the debouncing? why not using a delay after every `digitalRead()`?

Comment: I doubt that's the issue, but the reason why I use it is because its just more reliable, and runs much better for the ram I'm pretty sure, sorry but I am very noob XD

Comment: Actually, can you post the same thing but without the doIt? and whatever is in the doIt put it in the if statements? Or edit mine.

Comment: If I remove the `doIt()`, I will just end up repeating the same lines of code in two if statements which is not so pretty ;) anyway try the edited answer I posted since it is working for me.

Comment: I'm just now figuring out how to make the Zone1 into Zone2 for the 2nd button, but thanks again!

Comment: Easy ;) I've re-edited my answer to do that as well.

Comment: Jeez, you are the best XD Thanks Again again again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking

```
if (value > 5)
{
  StatementOne;
  statementTwo;
}
```

But I think you might want to write a function, which would look like this

```
void doThing(int button, int led)
{
  if (digitalRead(button))
     digitalWrite(led);
}
```

[Edit after reading your comment]
So you need to store the state of the system as a variable in the code.

```
bool state = false;
if (button1 && !state)
{
  state = true;
  // Your on code.
} 
if (button2 && state)
{
  state = false; 
  // Your off code
}
```

You need to add your existing code for turning your LCD and LED on and off where the comments are.
The state variable holds the on or off state of your LCD and LED.
You can of course split it even further so your LCD and LED come on separately of each other.

Does that help?  If so don't forget to mark it as answered.

Comment: What I mean is, I have 2 button commands, so if I press it, show something on LCD and led turns on, then when I press it again, do opposite.  I did that with the If command and it worked, but I want 2, so its the same thing but on a different pin

Comment: OK, I've edited the answer, because I can't type code in a comment, hope that helps, if not tell me why and I'll have another go :)

Comment: Actually, that would work as well! I need to put another command, so ill use this for my sensors! Thank you!